# Is it possible to log the exception "Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of ..." in WCF trace file (.svclog)?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, out-of-memory

My application is consuming a WCF service hosted on IIS, where the server machine has a RAM size of 4GB. When I invoke service request from my client application, I'm getting the exception "Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 134217728 bytes. The amount of available memory may be low". Though the try-catch block in the service didn't catch the exception, I got the exception in the client application. Hence I enabled the WCF tracing and verified the .svclog file for this text. It seems like this exception was not logged in the trace file either.

Is it possible to log this exception? If so, would it be possible to do it through trace file and how should I configure my WCF to enable that?

Please find below the snippet of config file I used to enable tracing in WCF.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source propagateActivity="false" name="System.ServiceModel"
        switchValue="Information, Critical, Error, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="xml">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Information, Critical, Error, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="xml">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="C:\Temp\logs\Traces.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
        name="xml" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId, Callstack">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add initializeData="C:\Temp\logs\Traces.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          name="xml">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please, share some details with us, maybe code, log files, errors, etc. It's hard to help without it

Comment: Are you sure this is happening on the server? What is the memory state of the client?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer At the time, the exception is thrown, the client has a memory state of approximately 700-800 MB. 

We started looking into this issue, when we got OutOfMemory exception from the client. The client application is 32-bit and was consuming around ~1.3-1.4 GB when we got this OutOfMemory exception. We did some code refactoring and reduce the consumption to around 800MB - 1GB. After code refactoring, we never got the OutOfMemory exception. Instead, we started getting this new exception  "Failed to allocate a managed memory buffer of 134217728 bytes."

Comment: The memory values is based on what we found in Visual Studio Diagnostic tools and Process Explorer tool by Microsoft.

Comment: @Renjith .Net is failing to get 134MB of **contiguous** memory at the client, presumably to receive the message. That's a large message, is it expected? The allocation may fail due to fragmented memory, especially if the [Large Object Heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap) is being used heavily. Is there any way you can make your messages smaller?

Comment: I think it depend on where the exception occurred. If you could provide the log sample, it would be good. Otherwise, please check where the exception occurred. If it occurred when the trace writing information to xml file, then I don't think you would be able to record the exception as the trace itself got the exception.